# Merge three tables columns with sql statement plus aggregate column count (Oracle11G2)

Tags: oracle, plsql, relational-database, inner-join, sql

I am a beginner to sql and was trying to create sql query to get data from these three tables below that I have described. 
"I need to show all of the Contacts that have number of clients greater then 1 and users that belong to them,and at last to group them by users."
 
Now this is sql statement that I was trying to create but I'm having sqlplus error ORA-00933, SQL command not properly ended just near "from client **as k**":

***select count(k.bkl), o.fnamek, o.lnamek, u.bu, u.fname, u.lname, k.namekl

from client AS k, contact AS o, usere AS u

where o.bko = k.bko and o.bu = u.bu and count(k.bkl) > 1

group by u.bu;***

CREATE TABLE Usere 
(bu NUMBER (2) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT pk1 PRIMARY KEY,
fname VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
lname VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
sector VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Contact
(bko NUMBER (2) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT pk2 PRIMARY KEY,
fnamek VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
lnamek VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
bu NUMBER (2) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT fk1 FOREIGN KEY (bu) REFERENCES Usere (bu)
);

CREATE TABLE Client
(bkl NUMBER (3) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT pk3 PRIMARY KEY,
namekl VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
address VARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,
bko NUMBER (2) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT fk2 FOREIGN KEY (bko) REFERENCES Contact (bko)
);

Can anyone help out? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle doesn't allow `as` in the `from` clause for table aliaes.  Plus,

- You should learn to use proper join syntax.
- You need to include all non-aggregated columns in the `group by`.
- Filtering on aggregation conditions (such as `count()`) belongs in a `having` clause.

  ```
  select count(k.bkl), o.fnamek, o.lnamek, u.bu, u.fname, u.lname, k.namekl
  from client k join
       contact o
       on o.bko = k.bko join
       usere u
       on o.bu = u.bu
  group by o.fnamek, o.lnamek, u.bu, u.fname, u.lname, k.namekl
  having count(k.bk1) > 1;
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I am aware that I need to learn a lot, as I said I am at the beginning stages of Oracle mastering.
Hello, I have tried to implement your query, and I'm getting "now rows selected" as output.
I have checked and there is definitely contacts with more then one clients in table client.
For example "select bkl from client where bko=10" returns 3 client names under that particular contact?

Comment: @user3586784 . . . Well, remove the `having` clause and you will see that the combination of columns is unique.

Comment: Is there anyway to get sorted view like to show number of counted clients, and not to repeat contact under each client that they have assigned to? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the sql query, I was looking for, and I have manage to figure it out:

```
select count(k.bkl) as Client_Number, o.fnamek as Contact_Name,
o.lnamek as Contact_Lastname, u.bu as User_ID, 
u.fname as User_Name, u.lname User_Lastname
from client k join
kontakt o
on o.bko = k.bko join
usere u
on o.bu = u.bu
group by o.fnamek, o.lnamek, u.bu, u.fname, u.lname
having count(k.bkl) > 1
```

Main problem with first code was that column k.namekl as a name of Client could not be in the aggregate sql statement count(k.bkl). I was trying to count the fields where Client are greater then 1 and at the same time show name of those clients. Thank you very much Gordon for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this query will help you to:

```
select * from
(
select count(k.bkl) over (partition by u.bu) bk1# , 
       o.fnamek, o.lnamek, u.bu, u.fname, u.lname, k.namekl
from client  k, contact  o, usere  u
where o.bko = k.bko and o.bu = u.bu 
)
where bk1#>1
```